# Can md5 function be passed a dynamic list of columns via a Parameter

Tags: expression, md5, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory v2 i am calling a Mapping Data Flow from a pipeline.  The source and sink connections in the dataflow are parameterized, so i can reuse the pipeline/data flow for multiple source/target combinations. However i want to create a derived column in the Dataflow which is a md5 hash of the appropriate columns for that particular source/target combination. Therefor i want to pass a list of columns into the md5() function which can be evaluated as the dataflow runs and an appropriate hash value can be generated for each row of data.  At the moment I can't find a way of getting it to work.

I have a dataflow parameter (pColumnList) of type string (there is no type option for array). The pipeline passes a string comma separated list of columnnames eg Col1,Col2,Col3
and the derived column (ROW_HASH) has the code/expression `md5($pColumnList)` the problem at the moment is that the function is hashing the string value of 'Col1,Col2,Col3' and therefore every row has the same hash value rather that the hash being calculated per row.  I've also tried splitting string into an array to see if the function will interpret the separate items as the columns ie  `md5(split($pColumnList,','))` but this results in an error as i don't think the md5 function accepts an array.

The problem is that as the source is dynamic, there's no defined schema in the dataflow that the expression can explicitly refer to at design time. I'm just wondering whether this is just simply not possible to do in adf mapping data flows and in fact we will either need a separate data flow creating for each specific source to target process with explicit source and target connections creating with their appropriate schema visible. (or alternatively the hash created as calculated column in the target table).

Answer (score 2):

We don't allow array values in those functions today.

Are you looking to generate a hash/fingerprint for the entire row?

If that's your goal, you'll need to use one of these methods:

1. Use toString(byPosition(1))+toString(byPositiong(2))+ ... in a derived column and concat each column into a new column, then hash that new column.
2. If the source is a file, use a source dataset without a delimiter, that just reads the entire row in as a single string. This way, you'll have the entire row as a single string (i.e. col_1) that you can hash.

Comment: thanks Mark the toString(byPosition(n)+..) would work for me in this scenario, i can construct an expression from the metadata based on the columns we need and pass that into the derived column.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc283k8CWh8

This demo shows how to get the values in a column array.

```
md5(byName($PrimaryKey))
```

for single value or

```
md5(byNames(split($Columns, ',')))
```

for an array generated by `split()`